# Extract a list of all methods from JavaDoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I have some package of javadoc, and I want to extract a list of all methods doumented inside. somethong like:

```
path="C:\Doc\idex.html"; 

List<String> listMethods=ExtractAPI(path);
```

I don't mind the language to do it, but I guess that java has a builtin features for it.

I tried reading the javadoc doumntation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html

But couldn't understand clear enough if it is possible, and if yes how exactly to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're extracting docs created by the standard Javadoc doclet you're in for a world of crappy HTML XPaths, because IIRC they're not marked with much that's useful--you need to know the structure. Just view source. Don't you have the jar or class files? What's your purpose?

Comment: @Dave: I have the javadoc and a jar file

Comment: All methods in alll classes? What's the benefit of having this list?

Comment: @sara IMO easier to use the jar file and a bytecode scanner, but if you're okay with grabbing info from HTML, I guess it's doable. Again--what's the purpose?

Comment: @Dave I don't mind extracting it from the jar, I just need the list.

Comment: @sara: Then you can create a simple recursive function and use reflection to obtain the method signatures.

Comment: @home can you post an answer and example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quickest solution is to unzip the jar then do something like this:

```
find . -name "*.class" | sed s/\.class// | xargs javap -private
```

This will produce output similar to the following for each `.class` file in the jar:

```
Compiled from "SHTMLPanelSingleDocImpl.java"
class com.lightdev.app.shtm.SHTMLPanelSingleDocImpl extends com.lightdev.app.shtm.SHTMLPanelImpl{
    public com.lightdev.app.shtm.SHTMLPanelSingleDocImpl();
    protected void initDocumentPane();
    protected void initActions();
}
```

Output may vary. For other decompilation options type `javap -help`.

If you need specifically-formatted output (that can't be grabbed from the above, which has pretty regular syntax thus is easily-manipulated) then `javap` may not be the best option. But since you refuse to state the purpose of the question, it's impossible to know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @sara If you're running Windows, install Cygwin. Otherwise do the same thing, but manually. Also note that saying something "doesn't work" provides nothing with which to diagnose failure.